# BottomSheetScaffold is overriding the background color of its parent

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I'm trying out `BottomSheetScaffold` and I just found a strange behavior (maybe a bug)  when using it.

I put it inside a `Box { }` that has a cyan background color:

```
composable(route = "my_route") {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(color = Color.Cyan),
    ) {
        val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()

        BottomSheetScaffold(
            scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
            sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp),
            sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp,
            sheetBackgroundColor = Color.Red,
            sheetContent = {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(96.dp)
                )
            }
        ) { }

        LaunchedEffect(key1 = null) {
            delay(1_500)
            coroutineScope.launch {
                bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.expand()
            }
        }

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(alignment = Alignment.Center),
            text = "Hello World",
            fontSize = 28.sp
        )
    }
}
```

But when I run the app and check that screen, the cyan background color is gone:

[image]

Here's how the background part should be:

[image]

---

**Am I forgetting to do something, is this the expected behavior or is this a bug?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

White color comes from `MaterialTheme.colors.background`, which is default value of `BottomSheetScaffold.backgroundColor` parameter. It's drawn on top of your `Box` background so it's not visible.

Also you don't need a `Box` here, it's intended to place content inside `content` parameter:

```
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()

BottomSheetScaffold(
    scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
    sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp),
    sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp,
    sheetBackgroundColor = Color.Red,
    backgroundColor = Color.Cyan,
    sheetContent = {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(96.dp)
        )
    }
) {
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = null) {
        delay(1_500)
        coroutineScope.launch {
            bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.expand()
        }
    }
    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(alignment = Alignment.Center),
            text = "Hello World",
            fontSize = 28.sp
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for the answer, @Pylyp Dukhov. If the content of the screen is encapsulated inside of the `BottomSheetScaffold`, do you know what should we do when the screen has two or more bottom sheets?

Comment: @AugustoCarmo should it be drawn one on top of an other? or just different content depending on action?

Comment: Different content depending on the action.

Comment: @AugustoCarmo so just display different views inside `sheetContent`, using `if` or `when`