# Composable screen with two or more BottomSheets

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

Through the question [BottomSheetScaffold is overriding the background color of its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72378164/bottomsheetscaffold-is-overriding-the-background-color-of-its-parent) it just came to my attention that when using using a `BottomSheetScaffold` we should place the content of the screen inside it (which, to me, is a bit odd).

Then the following question came to my mind. **What should we do when a Screen has two or more Bottom Sheets?**

```
sheetContent = {
    when (condition) {
        CONTENT_A -> { }
        CONTENT_B -> { }
        CONTENT_C -> { }
    }
}
```

I don't think this is the best answer as long as each bottom sheet may have a different configuration or even one is a `ModalBottomSheetLayout` and one other a `BottomSheetScaffold`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the official framework from Accompanist by Google to use a navcontroller to switch between bottom sheets: https://google.github.io/accompanist/navigation-material/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```kotlin
val activeDialog = remember {
    mutableStateOf("1")
}
```

sheet content

```kotlin
sheetContent = {
    when(activeDialog.value) {
        "1" -> {
            Column {
                Text(text = "Dialog1")
            }
        }
        "2" -> {
            Column {
                Text(text = "Dialog2")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and use show

```kotlin
activeDialog.value = "1"
dialogsState.show()
```

This is two lines, but it works